# What is machine-id?

Tags: security, firefox, sandbox, apparmor

Just read the machine-id manpage, still not clear on how it's used by applications. QuiteRSS and Firefox among others seem to use it. Is it generally safe to blacklist (using apparmor) certain applications from reading machine-id?